# Owin URL Rewrite to different port

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin, katana

We have a series of smaller APIs part of a larger system, each running in their own sites on an IIS machine.

To hide our internal architecture, we've created a series of IIS rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="AuthServer" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^auth/.*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:4000/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

However, we need to extend this system and make it testable.

We've tried:

```
if (context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("test"))
{
    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/rewritten");
}
```

But this only allows us to change the path. We need to rewrite to a different port/site.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find a way to do this, so we ended up using:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.getwebconfiguration(v=vs.90).aspx

To dynamically update the web.config rewrite rules from code. It works fine, and is testable (though not locally hosted).